# Is there Hidden Captcha in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I read the conversation in the thread https://www.drupal.org/node/2421919 that Honeypot will replace the Hidden Captcha in Drupal 8. Is it true?
Because I have a newsletter field which I want to protect from spams and honeypot will fail in this case as there is only 1 textbox which will hardly take 2-3 seconds to fill.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add **honeypot** to your own forms, or to any form through your own module's hook_form_alter's, by simply place the following function call inside your form builder function (or inside a hook_form_alter):

```
honeypot_add_form_protection($form, $form_state, array('honeypot', 'time_restriction'));
```

Note that you can **enable or disable either the honeypot field, or the time restriction** on the form by including or not including the option in the array.

In you case, you could remove the `time_restriction` in your newsletter form.

You can also use [Honeypot's API](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/honeypot/tree/honeypot.api.php) to modify the time delay for forms, add or remove protections for certain forms, etc.

---

I hope it will help you resolve your issue.